# What is the proper terminology for origin vs non-origin branches?

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand the relevant terminology in git regarding the division between origin and non-origin spaces in the local repo.

Consider the following scenario. I have branch `foo` checked out, and I would like to rebase it onto `master`, but first I want to make sure `master` is up-to-date with the remote repo.
I could do this:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout foo
git rebase -i master
```

This works fine. But I can avoid having to checkout `master` if I do a fetch and then rebase onto `origin/master` instead.

```
git fetch -a
git rebase -i origin/master
```

In trying to explain the difference between these two approaches to a co-worker, I realized I don't know the difference in terminology between `origin/master` and `master`. Can anyone educate me on the proper vocabulary here?

Comment: What is your upstream set as? Most of the time it's origin, so origin/master and master are the same thing.

Comment: My upstream is set to `origin`. But how can `origin/master` and `master` be the same thing? They're both distinct local branches on my machine. If I `git fetch -a`, `origin/master` will be changed, but `master` will not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`master` is a branch.  Sometimes you might call it a "local branch".  If you want to be very specific, you could say that it's a ref under `refs/heads`.

`origin/master` is a remote tracking ref.  Some people call this a remote tracking branch.  (I think even the docs might use that term at least in some places.)  That's unfortunate, because it's not a good name for what `origin/master` is, for at least two reasons:

1. If I have `master` and it tracks `origin/master`, that *also* means that the repo I have listed as the `origin` remote has a branch called `master`.  The `master` branch on `origin` is distinct from the `origin/master` ref on my local repo, and if anything is a "remote branch" it's the branch on the remote repo¹.  Sticking the word "tracking" in the middle doesn't make it less confusing; acknowledging that remote tracking refs are a different type of ref from branches does.
2. It suggests that `origin/master` is a type of branch.  Certainly `origin/master` is a type of *ref*, and it's usually (not always) related to a local branch, and it's related to a branch on the remote.  But it does not behave like a branch.  If you check it out, you are in detached head state; and so committing does not advance it.  It has its own convention for how it moves (governed by communication with the remote).

Unambiguously it is a ref under `refs/remotes/origin`.

---

¹The importance of that distinction shows through when you suggest that rebasing to `origin/master` is a substitute for `pull`ing and then rebasing to `master`.  It's not because your `origin/master` may not reflect where `master` on `origin` is *now*; it only reflects where `master` on `origin` *was* the last time you updated your remote refs for `origin`.  It *would* be roughly equivalent to `fetch` and the rebase to `origin/master`, with the difference that this leaves `master` behind `origin/master`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. When I run `git remote show origin`, those `refs/remotes/origin/...` lines appear as you state.

Comment: I haven't found a useful flowchart diagram taking into account remote-tracking refs, so I made one based on my understanding of your explanation. Would you mind looking at it and making sure everything (both the vocabulary and the workflow) is accurate? https://i.imgur.com/8wxAINB.png

Comment: @JacobStamm - That seems accurate in the common case at least.  Because of the wide range of ways merge and rebase can be used, they're a bit of an awkward fit here.  (For example, if you separately fetch and merge instead of pull, then you will `merge origin/master` and the merge arrow would arguably start further to the right.)  And it must be understood that each place in your diagram where an arrow crosses a line, those intermediate areas are updated as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Here's a modified version. I'm not sure it's intuitively obvious, but hopefully it's a little bit better https://i.imgur.com/RH6AiR1.png

Answer (score 2):

`origin/master` is a [pointer](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) to a remote branch, it is pointing to the `master` branch in the remote `origin`.   `master` is a local branch.  They are two distinct things (but can be somewhat connected by setting an `upstream` branch of a local branch).  Not all local branches have an upstream branch.

You cannot directly change what `origin/master` is pointing to locally.  You can only do that through a `push`.

You could add another remote, say `fred` (with `git remote add`).  `fred` may have a `master` branch as well, and would show up in your repo as `fred/master`.  Your local `master` would not have `fred/master` as an `upstream` branch (by default, but you could change that).

Comment: *`origin/master` is a remote branch* Well, almost. It's a **remote-tracking branch**! I.e., it's a branch in the local repository that tracks remote branch (branch `master` in the remote `origin`).

Comment: @phd - it's a *ref* in the local repository that tracks a remote branch.  Saying it's a branch is at best debatable, as trying to use it in contexts where the docs call for a branch will not do what's expected.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, good one.  git-scm uses the term "pointer": " pointer to where its master branch is, and names it origin/master locally" (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Comment: [This blog post](https://blog.plover.com/2017/06/17/) explains things quite clearly, however the author does make the understandable mistake of referring to `origin/*` as a branch. As per @MarkAdelsberger's answer, I think "remote-tracking ref" is probably the most accurate and clear term to be used. "Remote-tracking pointer" is a good choice too.

Answer (score 1):

Git documentation is sometimes not very good about making clear distinctions, but in general, names like `master` are called *branch names* and names like `origin/master` are *remote tracking branch names*.

I dislike the latter phrase as it is far too easy to mix them up, especially if you drop a word or re-order a word or two.  My new preferred term is *remote-tracking names*, since if you drop the hyphenated term it's clear that you're being unclear :-) , and if you drop the noun instead of the adjective, the hyphenated term *remote-tracking* is still fairly clear.

This still leaves a lot of room for confusion with *remote*, which is the term for names like `origin` itself: `git remote` manipulates these *remotes*, which are mostly just ways to remember a long URL.  It is also easy to confuse this with the verb *track* or *tracking*, which has about 40 million different meanings in Git. :-)  OK, not that many, but too many:

- A branch with some other name set as its *upstream* is said to to *track* that upstream.
- A file is *tracked* if and only if that file's path name is in the index, otherwise it is *untracked*.
- A *remote-tracking name* is a name like `origin/master`.

Git's *names*, like `master` and `origin/master`, are names in [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).  The namespace names all start with `refs/`; branch names are specifically refs (or references) starting with `refs/heads/`, tag names start with `refs/tags/`, and remote-tracking names start with `refs/remotes/` (and go on to include the name of the remote plus another slash).  (One can argue over whether the special names `HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, and so on are also refs / references.  Git itself mostly says they're not, except when it says that they are....)

Comment: I found out accidentally that you can put just about anything in `.git/` (outside `refs`) and have it treated like a ref (or symbolic ref), so at a technical level I'd say git treats those special names as refs - and as not all that special.  But that's based on observation; I've not dug through the code, and don't know if some *other* part of the system treats them differently.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: the interesting things about them include that they never get packed. Moreover, per `reachable.c`, it appears that `*_HEAD` are not consulted to test reachability. There was a bug in Git through 2.15.0 that would remove the commit to which a detached HEAD in an added work-tree pointed; d0c39a49ccb5dfe7feba4325c3374d99ab123c59 fixes this by having reachability.c explicitly look at each worktree's `HEAD`, but it still does not look at, e.g., `ORIG_HEAD` or `FETCH_HEAD`.